# Browser refresh error in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an application in asp.net 2.0.
In one form i have a button, and on click which will insert data into database.
now after inserting if i click bowser refresh button i am getting the following error.

> Refresh detected  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Refresh detected
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Refresh detected]
>   WebTemplate.Template.RefreshProtectModule.appl_AcquireRequestState(Object
>   source, EventArgs e) +351
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Hitting refresh is actually the same as clicking the button to insert data again.  Your button click event should probably redirect the user to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're using something called "RefreshProtectModule" which does not allow refresh. On one hand that's good - otherwise your form would insert record into DB on every refresh. On the other - you have to handle the "Refresh detected" exception and handle it graciously.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. can you suggest a better way to handle the "Refresh detected" and supress the request.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with this module, it could be something custom - check your website settings and talk to someone who must've installed it